# Did Atlassian SDK install JIRA automatically?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I followed the steps here: https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project to install Atlassian SDK for JIRA plugin development.

To my surprise, when I ran "atlas-run", JIRA was launched. I was wondering if SDK installed JIRA during the installation?

The reason why I asked this is that I followed this documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/learn-the-development-platform-by-example/create-a-plugin-skeleton to create a refapp skeleton. But when I tried to launch JIRA, JIRA launched failed withe the following error:

```
    JIRA Startup Failed
    The following plugins are required by JIRA, but have not been started:
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Gadgets Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.gadgets)
    JIRA Projects Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin)
    Atlassian OAuth Consumer Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.consumer)
    Atlassian Navigation Links Plugin (com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-nav-links-plugin)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - OAuth Service Provider SPI (com.atlassian.jira.oauth.serviceprovider)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Issue Navigation (com.atlassian.jira.jira-issue-nav-plugin)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Quick Edit Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.jira-quick-edit-plugin)
    Atlassian OAuth Admin Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.admin)
    Atlassian REST - Module Types (com.atlassian.plugins.rest.atlassian-rest-module)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Project Config Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.jira-project-config-plugin)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - REST Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.rest)
    Opensocial Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.opensocial)
    Applinks Product Plugin (com.atlassian.applinks.applinks-plugin)
    Atlassian OAuth Service Provider Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Look And Feel Logo Upload Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.lookandfeel)
    Embedded Gadgets Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.embedded)
    Gadget Spec Publisher Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - OAuth Consumer SPI (com.atlassian.jira.oauth.consumer)
    RPC JIRA Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.ext.rpc)
    Gadget Directory Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.directory)
    Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - SAL Plugin (com.atlassian.sal.jira)
    Gadget Dashboard Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard)
```

I suspect JIRA is locked so I need to delete the .jira.lock file, which I need to figure out what the JIRA_Home directory is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Atlassian SDK does not "install" JIRA out of the box. If you issue `atlas-run` from within a plugin project, the SDK will fetch all necessary dependencies for a JIRA instance via Maven and install a development version of JIRA into the `target` folder of your current plugin.

I'd suggest to create a clean plugin from scratch via `atlas-create-jira-plugin`as the refapp may be outdated.

https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/working-with-the-sdk/command-reference/atlas-create-jira-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I started with atlas-create-jira-plugin and it worked. I suspect probably something went wrong when converting a component for refapp to a servlet module...

Comment: Okay, cool, then please feel free to mark my answer as "correct". ;)